# Emulating WinKey+ArrowKey Functionality from win7 to linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, window-manager, key-binding, metacity

I much prefer Linux over windows but one thing I've always found win7 to be better at was managing and moving windows to different parts of the screen. I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can replicate the functionality of holding the windows key and pressing an arrow key in win7 on Linux. I use RHEL 6.5 with Gnome/Metacity daily but I'd also like to know how to do it in Ubuntu.

I know metacity has keybindings that can move a window to the right side of the screen, but win+right on win7 will automatically maximize vertically and make the width half the screen and remember the old position if I follow it with win+left. I'd love to be able to do that on Linux. Further, I'd like support for dual monitors, metacity's keybinding for 'move_to_side_w' will bring the window all the way to the left side of the left monitor even if the window is on the right monitor. I much prefer win7's functionality of automatically using half of the monitor that the window is currently on.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what GNOME version are you using, but there are some plugins out there like [gtile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) and [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/).

[Found this page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts) where the tile shortcurts are listed, but I do not use GNOME to test it. Maybe there is a disabled shortcut entry for this somewhere.

On Cinnamon (I use it) the window tiling shortcuts are default as windows and you can also ["snap" a window](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2013/07/new-window-tiling-and-snapping-functionality/), so it becomes something similar to the "always on top" feature, but having its own space. You can see what it is by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6zpcqhgyXI).